# Chrome Headless fails on CI when running build-agent as a service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, azure-devops, google-chrome-headless, build-agent

I have an angular (5) project running jasmine unit-tests using karma & chrome headless. This works fine locally but fails on our VSTS CI server (Custom Windows 10 VM with node & chrome [69] installed).

The build-agent installed on the VSTS VM runs as a windows service, which fails the chrome headless tests with a timeout:

```
2018-10-03T12:28:51.8716712Z [32m03 10 2018 12:28:04.336:INFO [karma]: [39mKarma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
2018-10-03T12:28:51.8717001Z [32m03 10 2018 12:28:04.336:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browser ChromeHeadless with unlimited concurrency
2018-10-03T12:28:51.8717325Z [32m03 10 2018 12:28:04.351:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser Chrome
2018-10-03T12:28:51.8717666Z [32m03 10 2018 12:28:40.937:INFO [HeadlessChrome 69.0.3497 (Windows 10.0.0)]: [39mConnected on socket vcUeG8L1qWsAFV7LAAAA with id 91653372
2018-10-03T12:28:51.8717989Z [33m03 10 2018 12:28:50.945:WARN [HeadlessChrome 69.0.3497 (Windows 10.0.0)]: [39mDisconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
2018-10-03T12:28:51.8718289Z [31mHeadlessChrome 69.0.3497 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR[39m
2018-10-03T12:28:51.8718600Z   Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.
2018-10-03T12:28:51.8718863Z 
2018-10-03T12:28:51.8719156Z HeadlessChrome 69.0.3497 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
2018-10-03T12:28:51.8719433Z   Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.
2018-10-03T12:28:51.8719704Z HeadlessChrome 69.0.3497 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
2018-10-03T12:28:51.8720051Z   Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.
```

If I change the build-agent to run in interactive mode the tests start working again. But this is a not ideal situation as in interactive mode we need to restart the build-agent manually when the server reboots.

Tests are run using:

```
ng test --code-coverage --browsers ChromeHeadless --single-run
```

karma.conf.js has custom launcher flags enabled:

```
--headless
--disable-gpu
--remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the build agent in interactive mode to run UI tests. Refer to this link for details: [Interactive vs. service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=vsts#account).